Azure Bot Framework Deployment Issue: Unable to Send Messages in Microsoft Teams Despite Successful Testing on Web Chat
I have deployed my bot using Azure Bot Framework on Azure App Services. It is working fine when I am testing on web chat. When I am trying to publish this app on my company's teams, it is not working. When I am trying to access this bot from my MS teams, I am getting error - "you can't send message to this bot". Can someone please provide with some solutions?
Issue I am getting while accessing bot on Teams
I have deployed the bot using Azure Bot Framework and it is working fine on Web Chat. But I am not able to access the bot on Teams. Can someone provide me suggestions regarding where am I going wrong and what else could I do?

Same issue is being tracked here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1664947/azure-bot-framework-deployment-issue-unable-to-sen. Please check that thread for further updates.
